# How to show text instead of integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a pull down list of Races (asian, caucasian, African/black, etc).
These races are represented by my Race model. I can create a record successfully, however, when I try to view the record the corresponding integer of the race is displayed and not the text.

How do I get the text associated instead of the integer id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you supply a minimum set of data for us to assist, I risk an answer as generically as I can.

If you are using a form_for builder

```
<%= f.collection_select :race_id, Race.all, :id, :name %>
```

or whatever you call your fields

If you are using a form_tag

```
<%= select_tag :race_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Race.all, "id", "name") %>
```

These are as I said pretty generic answers, you can build further on them. Check this link for more:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the value of the selected option which is the index of the array I imagine. You can use that index to get the text value from your races array. Without seeing more code that is all I can provide.